# Mule cloud connector @connect method failing to be called on mule startup

Tags: mule, mule-studio

What are the likely causes when the @connect method of my connector fails to be hit in a cloud connector I'm working on? My project is constructed from the Maven cloud connector archetype.

The @source gets called fine and the update site is generated fine in Maven and imported into Mule Studio.

```
/**
 * @param configFileLocation  config File Location
 */
@Connect
public void connect(final String configFileLocation)
    throws ConnectionException {

    System.out.println("Connect called");
    <connect code in here...>
}
@Source
    public void inboundEndpoint(final String sessionID,
            final SourceCallback callback) {
        getSessionSourceCallbackMap().put(sessionID, callback);
    }
```

Could it be to do with the fact that I don't need to have user and password params in the connect method?
I suspect I will need to dig around in the generated update site code..

maybe this helps:  after stepping through some code the debugger pauses on:

```
  ConnectorInjectionAdapter connector = new ConnectorInjectionAdapter();
```

and in InboundEndpointMessageSource.java, a unhandled exception is caught

```
finally {
            if (connection!= null) {
                try {
                    castedModuleObject.releaseConnection(new FixConnectorConnectionManager.ConnectionKey(transformedConfigFileLocation), connection);
                } catch (Exception _x) {
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Can you add more detail?

Comment: @Seba no I am not I am afraid, no exceptions, devkits a bit of a black box to me I'm afraid, I was just trusting that its compiling to the update site would work..the connector icon and intergration with Mule Studio looks ok though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to have the method marked @ValidateConnection with a non true value (the default method stubb)

```
@ValidateConnection
public boolean isConnected() {
    //code to say whether connected or not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Basic check: your class should be annotated with `@Connector` not `@Module`.*

Try doing the following:

- Add `@ConnectionKey` to the `configFileLocation` argument of the `connect()` method,
- Add `@ConnectionIdentifier` on `getConfigFileLocation()` (add the getter if you don't have it)

and see what happens.

Comment: thanks :) I tried your suggestions but still no luck, FYI I get some exception thrown at the line 163 = FooConnectorInjectionAdapter connector = new FooConnectorInjectionAdapter(); inside /mule-transport-foo-devkit/target/generated-sources/mule/org/mule/transport/foo/adapters/FooConnectorConnectionManager.java

Comment: also I used:> @Connector(name = "foo", schemaVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT")
public class FooConnector {

Comment: I also tried adding this but no luck: public void connect(@ConnectionKey final String configFileLocation, @Password final String password)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's going on in your connector. Having a `@Password` annotated param is not required. Is it super secret or can you share the code somewhere?